# Number of solutions to $x^2+yz=1$ (mod $p$). Where is my mistake?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Number of solutions $N$ to $x^2+yz=1$ (mod $p$) where $p>2$ and $p$ is a prime. Where is my mistake?

From my lecture notes I know that: ($e(z)=e^{2\pi i z}$)
$$
N = p^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\sum_{x=1}^{p}\sum_{y=1}^{p}\sum_{z=1}^{p}e(k(x^2+yz-1)/p).
$$
$$
= p^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}e(-k/p)\sum_{x=1}^{p} e(kx^2/p)\sum_{y=1}^{p}\sum_{z=1}^{p}e(kyz/p)
$$
In the next step I use two lemmas proved before that say
$$
\sum_{y=1}^{p}\sum_{z=1}^{p}e(kyz/p) = p (k,p) \quad ((k,p)=gcd(k,p))
$$
and
$$
(*) \quad \sum_{x=1}^{p} e(kx^2/p) = G(k,p), \quad G(k,p)=\sum_{a=1}^{p} \left( \frac{a}{p} \right) e(ak/p)
$$
So now $N$ becomes
$$
=p^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}e(-k/p) G(k,p) \, p \,(k,p)
$$
And writing the Gauss sum (The fraction is Legendre symbol) with its definition (above), changing order of summation and noting that $(k,p)=1$ gives
$$
=\sum_{a=1}^{p} \left( \frac{a}{p} \right) \sum_{k=0}^{p-1}e(k(a-1)/p) 
$$
Which equals $0$ because the inner sum is $0$ except when $p|(a-1)$ which never happens.

There must be mistake or multiple mistakes somewhere because obviously the answer is not zero.

Comment: For $a=1$ we have $p\mid a-1$.

Comment: Well I think that still makes the last sum zero. Or maybe there my thinking goes wrong?

Comment: @DietrichBurde then the sum is just p? Which is obviously wrong too..